# Strip a section out of a url in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following URL that is being returned to me from the Vzaar upload api:

```
https://vz1.s3.amazonaws.com/vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4vz1vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4"c9f4852682649c4a1c034af092b2938f"
```

I need to be able to strip just the first "vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a" out of the url.  Is there any way to do this in PHP?

Thank you in advance for any help that you provide.

Comment: As a note, the string that I need stripped out will always be different, however it will always rest between the two slashes that it is in between.

Comment: How consistent is the url you are going to use?  Are they always going to look like this?

Comment: Is it always after `/source/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string seems to appear twice in your URL (is it even a valid URL?). You also did not define any rules for obtaining it, so here I just take the 5th "part" separated by slashes.

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://vz1.s3.amazonaws.com/vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4vz1vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4"c9f4852682649c4a1c034af092b2938f"';
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    $parts = explode('/', $parsed['path']);
    echo $parts[5];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It is a valid url.  I am using the Vzaar video platform to host videos and in order to have Vzaar process the uploaded video, I need to grab the 'guid' for the uploaded video, which is that part that I needed stripped out.

Comment: I see. If any of the answers to this question helped solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer to your question by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is take the string right after the "source" tag. Done by exploding.

```
$a = 'https://vz1.s3.amazonaws.com/vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4vz1vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4"c9f4852682649c4a1c034af092b2938f';
$parts = explode('/', $a);
$i = 0;
for(; $i < count($parts); $i++)
    if($parts[$i] == 'source')
        break;
$i++;
echo $parts[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always between slashes, you can explode() on / and grab the n-th item.

Answer (score 0):

Is the string always at the exact same location? if so, how about something like...

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://vz1.s3.amazonaws.com/vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4vz1vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4"c9f4852682649c4a1c034af092b2938f"';
  $url = parse_url($url);
  $url = explode('/',$url['path']);
  print_r($url[5]);
?>
```

The above code would print vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a

Comment: Actually use explode instead of split.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'https://vz1.s3.amazonaws.com/vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4vz1vzaar/vz8/2b5/source/vz82b51a36989c422abc4db1734208933a/test.mp4"c9f4852682649c4a1c034af092b2938f"';
$str = substr($str, strpos($str, 'source/') + 7);
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '/'));
```

At this example, the position of 'source' in the URL is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party here, but you shouldn't need to do that

The GUID will be returned to you in the XML response from the first step in the upload process.

http://developer.vzaar.com/docs/version_1.0/uploading/sign.html

See the example at the bottom, you can pull the GUId straight from there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vzaar-api>
 <guid>vz7651d8c2558b46179531548224c87f84</guid>
  <key>vz7/651/source/vz7651d8c2558b46179531548224c87f84/${filename}</key>
  <https>false</https>
  <acl>private</acl>
  <bucket>vzaar_development_bucket</bucket>
  <policy>ewogICAgICAnZ ... JywgIF0KICAgICAgfQ==</policy>
  <expirationdate>2009-06-11T00:05:43.000Z</expirationdate>
  <accesskeyid>96ZODEDA709P5JNKI6X08U7PBQ31GUY8</accesskeyid>
  <signature>1ZwSGQjv4nrKUM1M/euO8FdxG20=</signature>
</vzaar-api>
```